# How to test if a type is abstract?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-store-apps, .net-4.6

IsAbstract does not seem to be there.  Where has it gone?

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsAbstractBaseClass()
{
  Type type = typeof(ViewModelBase);
  Assert.IsTrue(type.IsAbstract);
}
```

Comment: More importantly, why would you need to test that a type is abstract or not? Unit tests should test how code works, not how it is written.

Comment: What error do you get? What .Net framework are you using?

Comment: @fcuesta - see question tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Windows Store applications you can use TypeInfo:

```
using System.Reflection;
type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract;
```

IsAbstract is not supported in .NET for Windows Store apps. 
If you check the method here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx
you will see there is no corresponding icon for Windows Store apps.

Answer (score 1):

Our repositories are required to use a base repository abstract class.  I verify compliance with a line in my test

```
Assert.IsTrue(instanceToBeTested is MyAbstractClassHere);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return True even if the class is derived from the abstract class?